# Will Android deliver notifications to apps outside of the play store?

Tags: android, cordova

I've got an app that I wrote and I'm testing on my phone. The notifications worked in the emulator but don't on my phone. I installed via the apk file.

Is it possible that I'm not receiving notifications because my app wasn't installed through the store?

Comment: I'll take a look at my code again and see if I can fix it. To keep this on topic if you can post that as an answer with some kind of reference I'll be happy to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no difference between you installing an app yourself and it installing from a store in how notifications are posted.